# Why can I not save preferences on Android?

Tags: libgdx

I'm using the code in this tutorial ([Full LibGDX game tutorial](https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/full-libgdx-game-tutorial-menu-control/)). The code to save the preferences works fine on Desktop but not on Android. Here's how I access and save my preferences:

```
public class AppPreferences {
private static final String PREF_MUSIC_VOLUME = "volume";
private static final String PREF_MUSIC_ENABLED = "music.enabled";
private static final String PREF_SOUND_ENABLED = "sound.enabled";
private static final String PREF_SOUND_VOL = "sound";
private static final String PREFS_NAME = "b2dtut";

protected Preferences getPrefs() {
    return Gdx.app.getPreferences(PREFS_NAME);
}

public boolean isSoundEffectsEnabled() {
    return getPrefs().getBoolean(PREF_SOUND_ENABLED, true);
}

public void setSoundEffectsEnabled(boolean soundEffectsEnabled) {
    getPrefs().putBoolean(PREF_SOUND_ENABLED, soundEffectsEnabled);
    getPrefs().flush();
}

public boolean isMusicEnabled() {
    return getPrefs().getBoolean(PREF_MUSIC_ENABLED, true);
}

public void setMusicEnabled(boolean musicEnabled) {
    getPrefs().putBoolean(PREF_MUSIC_ENABLED, musicEnabled);
    getPrefs().flush();
}

public float getMusicVolume() {
    return getPrefs().getFloat(PREF_MUSIC_VOLUME, 0.5f);
}

public void setMusicVolume(float volume) {
    getPrefs().putFloat(PREF_MUSIC_VOLUME, volume);
    getPrefs().flush();
}

public float getSoundVolume() {
    return getPrefs().getFloat(PREF_SOUND_VOL, 0.5f);
}

public void setSoundVolume(float volume) {
    getPrefs().putFloat(PREF_SOUND_VOL, volume);
    getPrefs().flush();
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Android, *for some reason* you have to store the reference to the `Preferences` object instead of accessing it using `Gdx.app.getPreferences(PREFS_NAME)`. It probably has to do with how Android's built-in preferences work and how `getPreferences` interracts with it but I am unsure of the exact reason why. To solve this simply make this change:

```
private Preferences preferences;

protected Preferences getPrefs() {
    if (preferences == null)
        preferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences(PREFS_NAME);
    return preferences;
}
```

Comment: In fact, it is fair for desktop apps too